# Piecewise linear regression with SAS PHREG

Tags: sas, cox-regression

How to implement a piecewise linear regression model in PHREG procedure of SAS?

For example with one knot at X=T:

Y = β_10 + β_11 . X   if X ≤ T

Y = β_20 + β_21 . X   if X >T

Given the model with the constraint of continuity:

```
Y = β_10 + β_11 . X   if X ≤ T

Y = β_10 + (β_11 - β_21) T + β_21 . X   if X >T
```

i.e :

```
Y= β_0 + β_1 . X + S_1
```

where

```
 S_1 =  ( β_11 - β_21 ) T  if X >T  and 0 otherwise.
```

Finally i would like to include it in a Cox model:

```
Proc PHREG
     Model  time * cas (censure) = X  S_1  ;
Run ;
```

But the problem is S_1 has unknown beta coefficients in it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is X a time or a categorical variable?

Comment: I forgot to mention it. Thanks for noticing.  X should be a continuous variable.